# itext : paragraph keepTogether property affect sub element indent

Tags: java, itext

I use keepTogether property on Paragraph to link on the same page some sub element (Chunk, Paragraph, etc.)

Java code:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\hello.pdf"));
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
pdf.addWriter(writer);
document.open();

Paragraph mainPara = new Paragraph();

Chunk title = new Chunk();
title.append("My title:");
title.setUnderline(1f, -2f);
mainPara.add(title);

Paragraph subPara = new Paragraph("Hello World!");
mainPara.add(subPara);

mainPara.setIndentationLeft(11f);
mainPara.setKeepTogether(true);

document.add(mainPara);

document.close();
```

When I activate the keepTogether property, I lost the indentationLeft inherited from mainPara on subPara element.

Without keepTogether property on mainPara object, the pdf result result is :

```
   My title:

   Hello World!
```

With keepTogether property on mainPara object, the pdf result result is :

```
   My title:

Hello World!
```

I lost the indent inherited from the mainPara on subPara object. I wan't to keep it.

Comment: could u explain by pic . what u wanted and what u r getting ?

Comment: I add a pdf result with and without keepTogether property

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting indentation for the main paragraph,

For a long text

```
subPara.setFirstLineIndent(11f);
```

OR For a short text.

```
subPara.setIndentationLeft(11f);
```